# drag&drop of div element

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a rectangular div element on a page with image and text span inside.
Div has 2px border to make it actually visible.

Then I add dragstart event listener to my div element.
dragstart event fires always if I start dragging the image inside div but it is very problematic if I start dragging by clicking on text span or blank place:

In Google Chrome dragging is very unstable. It can work a few times then stops firing, then work again and so on.
In Mozilla Firefox it doesn't work at all.

How to fix it and allow drag by clicking on any point inside bound rect of my div?

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://www.wigwam3d.com/previews/1f/1ffbf8da-a4d0-4e40-b9e1-0329220969dc.jpg">
  <div>Element</div>
</div>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/673ytif50cViE5dTv3df?p=preview

Comment: Do you have some code for us?

Comment: Show your code when you Ask..

Comment: code and any console messages would be peachy - you've been spoiled your last two questions, no code, only external link, surely you know how SO works by now after 50+ questions

Comment: Here in the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/673ytif50cViE5dTv3df?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a simple solution: add attribute draggable=true on div element! That's all!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code , you can drag div anywhere on the window. Also fix width and height of the div.

$(function(){
  $("#animation").css({"cursor":"move"})

```
// mousedown:fn(){dragging = true;}


var dragging = false;
var iX, iY;
$("#animation").mousedown(function(e) {
    dragging = true;
    iX = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
    iY = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
    this.setCapture && this.setCapture();
    return false;
});

// mouseover:fn(){dragging = tru;}

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (dragging) {
        var e = e || window.event;
        var oX = e.clientX - iX;
        var oY = e.clientY - iY;
        $("#animation").css({"left":oX + "px", "top":oY + "px"});
        return false;
    }
};
```

// mouseup:fn(){dragging = false;}

```
$('#animation').mouseup(function(e) {
    dragging = false;
    this.releaseCapture && this.releaseCapture();
    e.cancelBubble = true;
})
```

})

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain a little bit why I can't use the native event and simulate it instead? It looks as slightly hacky solution))